# Convert an HTML string to DOM and then DOM to Formatted Text

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have used an [RtfToHtml Converter](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e)  in order to print some text into my table cell. it converts successfully, then I want this converted text (geResult.NotesLong) to be formatted:

```
<td>
    <script>{ setCommentValue(@colIndex, @rowIndex, @totalColCount, '@geResult.NotesLong', '@geResult.Color');}</script>
</td>
```

This JavaScript function converts it into a DOM element

```
function setCommentValue(colIndex, rowIndex, assessmentLength, resultValue, color) {

var str2DOMElement = function (html) {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    frame.contentDocument.open();
    frame.contentDocument.write(html);
    frame.contentDocument.close();
    var el = frame.contentDocument.body.firstChild;
    document.body.removeChild(frame);
    return el;
  }

 var el = str2DOMElement(resultValue);

 //...code to set elementPos...

 $(".test").get(elementPos).appendChild(el);

}
```

which displays in my table as follows

```
<DIV STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12;color:#000000;"><P STYLE="margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN><SPAN>Lee is an attentive listener who tunes into the task at hand  </SPAN></SPAN></P><P /></DIV>
```

However I want it to display as (with formatting defined in the above tags)

```
Lee is an attentive listener who tunes into the task at hand
```

How do I format this text so that it is formatted as per tags but only text is displayed in my table cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have found a way to extract plain text from inside (but it is still missing formats)

**html page**

```
<td>
    <script>{ setCommentValue(@colIndex, @rowIndex, @totalColCount, '@geResult.NotesLong', '@geResult.Color');}</script>
</td>
```

**javascript**

```
function setCommentValue(colIndex, rowIndex, assessmentLength, resultValue, color) {

String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

//replace all text special characters
var replaced = resultValue.replaceAll("&amp;", "&").replaceAll("&gt;", ">").replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replaceAll("&quot;", "\"").replaceAll("&#039;", "\'");

var parser = new DOMParser();    
var doc = parser.parseFromString(replaced, "text/xml");       

....

$(".test").get(elementPos).innerHTML = doc.firstChild.textContent;

}
```

My text had special characters like > for > etc so i replaced them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your code ends like this:

```
[...]</P><P /></DIV>
```

There's an error, it shoud be

```
[...]</P></P></DIV>
```

(second closing `p` tag wrong `/` position)

ADDITION: Actually, that second closing p tag is one too much - there's only one opening `p`tag in the code you posted - erase it.

Comment: the second is an empty <P /> tag..but even after erasing it the text remains along with the tags