# DOMParser behaves unexpected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, domparser

This post is related to [Convert a HTml String to DOM and then DOM to formatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859034/convert-a-html-string-to-dom-and-then-dom-to-formatted-text/43861538#43861538)

I have the following DOM string

```
<DIV STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12;color:#000000;">
<P STYLE="margin:0 0 0 0;">
<SPAN><SPAN>Lee  is an attentive listener who tunes into the task at hand and follows instructions. 
</SPAN></SPAN></P><P />
<P STYLE="margin:0 0 0 0;">
<SPAN>
<SPAN>In our reading lessons we have been working on books from Levels 6 to 9 with support given as needed. 
</SPAN></SPAN></P><P />
<P STYLE="margin:0 0 0 0;">
<SPAN>
<SPAN>Lee can write his own simple stories and recounts of 2 or 3 sentences. 
</SPAN></SPAN></P><P />
</Div>
```

when i parse this string with DOMParser it creates

doc.firstChild.textContent as

```
Lee  is an attentive listener who tunes into the task at hand and follows instructions. In our reading lessons we have been working on books from Levels 6 to 9 with support given as needed.Lee can write his own simple stories and recounts of 2 or 3 sentences.
```

doc.firstChild.children.length as 7

doc.firstChild.children.item(0) as

```
Lee  is an attentive listener who tunes into the task at hand and follows instructions
```

doc.firstChild.children.item(1) as null

doc.firstChild.children.item(2) as

```
 In our reading lessons we have been working on books from Levels 6 to 9 with support given as needed.
```

doc.firstChild.children.item(4) as

```
Lee can write his own simple stories and recounts of 2 or 3 sentences.
```

all others items are null

Also, all 7 of the children above have a nodeName **P**

it really doesn't make sense to me

also there is no spacing between the paragraphs when i append it to my table cell.

```
$(".test").get(elementPos).appendChild(doc.firstChild);
```

### Doc is created as follows (*replaced* is the above mentioned DOM String  .... )

```
  var parser = new DOMParser();    
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(replaced, "text/xml");
```

Comment: you don't say what you expect

Comment: you also don't show how `doc` is created (you say DOMParser, but it sure doesn't look like you're using DOMParser, as DOMParser would result in doc.firstChild.children.length = 2 (head and body are the two elements)

Comment: i expect that there is paragraphing of my text as is mentioned also if i add <b> and <i> texts, it should display as bold and italic

Comment: i have now mentioned doc creation in my post too